# CodeIgniter Active Record not equal

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter using active record, how do I perform a not equal to in `$this->db->where()`.  For instance:

```
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId', $campaignId);
```

Will do equal to, but I need not equal to.  I have tried:

```
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId <> ', $campaignId);
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId != ', $campaignId);
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId', ' != ' . $campaignId);
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId != ' . $campaignId);
```

All with no luck.  Ideas?

Answer (score 90):

According to the manual this should work:

> Custom key/value method:
>
> You can include an operator in the first parameter in order to control the comparison:

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->where('id <', $id);
Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' AND id < 45
```

Search for `$this->db->where();` and look at item #2.

Comment: **Small Note: Space is must between field name and operator (as given in above example)**. I was trying without giving space between field name and operator. It wasn't working.

Answer (score 22):

It worked fine with me,

```
$this->db->where("your_id !=",$your_id);
```

Or try this one,

```
$this->db->where("your_id <>",$your_id);
```

Or try this one,

```
$this->db->where("your_id IS NOT NULL");
```

all will work.

Answer (score 11):

Try this code. 
This seems working in my case.

```
$this->db->where(array('id !='=> $id))
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$this->db->where('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId !=' , $campaignId);
```

This should work (which you have tried)

To debug you might place this code just after you execute your query to see what exact SQL it is producing, this might give you clues, you might add that to the question to allow for further help.

```
$this->db->get();              // your query executing

echo '<pre>';                  // to preserve formatting
die($this->db->last_query());  // halt execution and print last ran query.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (which you have tried)

```
$this->db->where_not_in('emailsToCampaigns.campaignId', $campaignId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from($this->table_proposals)
->where('customer_id', $this->session->userdata('user')['customer_id'])
->where('status <>' , 'draft')
->get()->result();
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the codeigniter documentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APpD3.png)

Comment: Please always paste the documentation part as text (not image) in the post, in case the site is no longer reachable in the future.