# Codeigniter mysql where not equal to query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

Mysql codeigniter query is not working properly. 
Suppose if mysql table looks like this:

```
 user_id|user_name
       1|john
       2|alex
       3|sam
```

Here **user_name** is unique

The following query should return **false** if **user_name=john** and **user_id=1** and **true** if say **user_name=john** and **user_id=2**.

```
$this->db->get_where('user', array('user_name' => $name,'user_id !=' => $userid));
```

But it returns **true** in the case **user_name=john** and **user_id=1**.

Can anyone suggest me an alternative way of querying not equal to.

print($this->db->last_query()) gives:

SELECT * FROM (user) WHERE user_name = 'john' AND user_id != '1'

Comment: Any chance you have any additional users with first name john?  That would return true as well.

Comment: try this and check what query is been executed
   print "SQL Query: ".$this->db->last_query();

Comment: ok this is how it looks like SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `user_name` = 'john' AND `user_id` != '1'. The 1 was the no of rows returned.

Comment: that was correct it will return true only you are checking whether user_id!= or not obviously user_id is not equal because 1 != 2 so it will return true

Comment: This will help you
[same question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226261/codeigniter-active-record-not-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use simple `$this->db->query('your query');`

Comment: i would suggest you to use procedures as they are pre parsed and complied and use $this->db->query('call yourprocedure('your parms')');

Comment: I am amazed that this is the accepted answer.  It makes no attempt to resolve the specific question asked and there is absolutely no intent to educate the OP or future researchers.  Very low value on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this, Add the desired condition in the where function.

```
$this -> db -> where('invitee_phone !=', $user_phone);
```

Comment: This entirely unexplained answer bears no resemblance to the question asked and fails to respect the actual challenge that the OP is facing.  Very low quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can go follwoing way too. It work for me

```
$total = 5;
$CI = get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
$CI->db->order_by('id','asc');
$topusers = $CI->db->get_where('users',array('user_type != 1  && `status` =' => 1),$total,0);
echo $CI ->db ->last_query();
die;
```

and if still not work for you can go with @rohit suggest: $this->db->query('your query');

Comment: Is `&&` valid sql syntax for _your_ db driver?  What is the point of using order_by?  Why is there an arbitrary limit of 5 imposed?  Why did you invent new/unmentioned table columns in your query?  `last_query()` doesn't produce a result set, it displays the rendered query.  This answer isn't much of an answer.  Not only is it doing bad/unnecessary things, there isn't a shred of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Type 1:**

Using `->where("column_name !=",$columnname)`  is fine for one column.

But if you want to check multi columns, you have to form an **array** inside **where** clause.

Like this

```
$whereArray = array(
                "employee_name" => $name,
                "employee_id !=" => $id,
        );

$this->db->select('*')->from('employee')->where($whereArray);
```

**Type 2:**

We can just write exactly what we want inside where.

Like

```
$thi->db->where(("employee_id =1 AND employee name != 'Gopi') OR designation_name='leader@gopis clan'");
```

*Type 2* is good for working with combining queries, i mean **paranthesis** "()"

Comment: The OP doesn't actually need to select any data into a result set; only a count is needed.  You are not fully embracing CI's query builder methods -- this makes your suggestion less portable.  Assuming variables would be involved in the where values, this technique will be unstable/insecure because there will be no automatic escaping.

Comment: anyway thanks for the != mark inside the string of array, that helps me alot to customize the Where statements... @AravidhGopi

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this code:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('employee')->where('user_name', $name)->where('user_id !=', $userid)->get();
$last_query = $this->db->last_query();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

if you pass $name = 'john' and $userid = '1' then it return empty array.

Comment: Not only do I believe the where logic is incorrect on this answer, the OP doesn't actually need to generate a result set of data from the query.  Only the count is required.  This is doing more than it needs to and there are more concise methods that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `$this->db->query('your query');` is that it is not portable.  One of the most important reasons to embrace the query builder methods is so that no matter what database driver you use, CodeIgniter ensures that the syntax is appropriate.

If a bit of discussion was possible, I'd probably like to hear why you need composite primary identifiers in your table and I'd like to see what your table schema looks like.  However, I think the time for discussion has long passed.

Effectively, you want to return a boolean result stating the availability of the combination of the username AND the id -- if one is matched, but not both, then `true` (available).

To achieve this, you will want to search the table for an exact matching row with both qualifying conditions, count the rows, convert that integer to a boolean, then return the opposite value (the syntax is simpler than the explanation).

Consider this clean, direct, and portable one-liner.

```
return !$this->db->where(['user_name' => $name,'user_id' => $userid])->count_all_results('user');
```

this will return `false` if the count is `> 0` and `true` if the count is `0`.