# codeigniter: where query in not condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

If this query for select all records where id =11

```
 $this->db->select('title')->from('mytable')->where('id', $id)->limit(10, 20);
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

then what is the query to select all records where **id != 11** in `CodeIgniter` style.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226261/codeigniter-active-record-not-equal duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it to the column part of the where, so

```
$this->db->select('title')->from('mytable')->where('id !=', $id)->limit(10, 20);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Btw, always check the codeigniter manual, it mentions it right with the `where()` [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) and it's one of the best documentations you are ever going to find.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$this->db->select('title')->from('mytable')->where('id !=', $id)->limit(10, 20);
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a professional and clean way :)

```
$where(array('id !' => $id, 'qty >' => '10'));
        $this->db->select('title');
        $this->db->from('mytable');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->limit(10, 20);
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Chained calls (with enters) are incomparably cleaner as this now has a huge number of (unreadable) `$this->db->`'s.  And taking out the argument from the where function makes it even worse, as now you have to ignore the variable first, read on, go back and read on again.